# Get Last message loaded based on message type

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which contains different messages, each with a messageType field. I need to fill a ASP.NET list control of the last loaded message for each messageType. My sql statement to return everything is:

```
SELECT MessageTypes.MessageType MessageType
    ,Messages.MessageDate
    ,Messages.ValueDate
    ,Messages.MessageReference
    ,Messages.Beneficiary
    ,Messages.StatusId
    ,MessageStatus.STATUS
    ,BICProfile.BIC
FROM Messages
INNER JOIN MessageStatus
    ON Messages.StatusId = MessageStatus.Id
INNER JOIN MessageTypes
    ON Messages.MessageTypeId = MessageTypes.MessageTypeId
INNER JOIN BICProfile
    ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId
WHERE (BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue')
    AND Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
```

So i need to pull back the last message for each message type.

***EDIT***
Some clarification on what the statusId is. These are basically used in conjunction with a users role, what messages that can see. So, i need to return the last loaded message for a given message type. Effectively, only looking to return 1 message for each message type. The messageId is unique, where the message date could be the same.

Comment: Do you want the last message for each message type where the status of the last message is 4, 5, or 6? Or do you want the last message of a status of 4, 5, or 6, for each message type? In other words, do you want the result for a message type when its last message is not 4, 5, or 6?

Comment: Also, what do you want to do in the event of a tie? In that case would you want the message with the highest ID?

Comment: In regards to your edit, I know you want the last loaded message for each message type, but if the status of that last message is something other than 4, 5, or 6, do you want it returned? Or do you want the last loaded message for each message type only considering messages with a status of 4, 5, or 6? As for your note about message ID, take a look at the 2nd query in my list, that will return the highest messageid when the messagedate is the same. In the other responses, they would have to add ", messageid desc" to the order by of the analytic function.

Comment: @ShWiVel, those are just examples, the StatudId could be more yes.

Comment: If you don't care about what the status is, just remove that from the WHERE clause. Also it sounds like you want only the highest messageid in an event there is a tie on messagedate. In this case, try running the 2nd query in my response, but take out status in(4,5,6) from the where clause.

Comment: Note: In the other responses right now, if there is a more recent message, but with a status of anything other than 4/5/6, they will actually ignore that more recent message, and only show you the latest message where the status is 4/5/6 (even if there is a more recent message in that category with a status of 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) Function to assign each of your messages a rank by Message date (starting at 1 again for each message type), then just limit the results to the top ranked message:

```
WITH AllMessages AS
(   SELECT  MessageTypes.MessageType, 
            Messages.MessageDate, 
            Messages.ValueDate, 
            Messages.MessageReference, 
            Messages.Beneficiary, 
            Messages.StatusId,
            MessageStatus.Status, 
            BICProfile.BIC,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Messages.MessageTypeId 
                                            ORDER BY Messages.MessageDate DESC)
    FROM    Messages 
            INNER JOIN MessageStatus 
                ON Messages.StatusId = MessageStatus.Id 
            INNER JOIN MessageTypes 
                ON Messages.MessageTypeId = MessageTypes.MessageTypeId 
            INNER JOIN BICProfile  
                ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId 
    WHERE   BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue'
    AND     Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
)
SELECT  MessageType, 
        MessageDate, 
        ValueDate, 
        MessageReference, 
        Beneficiary, 
        StatusId,
        Status, 
        BIC 
FROM    AllMessages
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

If you can't use `ROW_NUMBER` then you can use a subquery to get the latest message date per type:

```
SELECT  Messages.MessageTypeID, MessageDate = MAX(Messages.MessageDate)
FROM    Messages
        INNER JOIN BICProfile  
            ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId 
WHERE   BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue'
AND     Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
GROUP BY Messages.MessageTypeID
```

Then inner join the results of this back to your main query to filter the results:

```
SELECT  MessageTypes.MessageType, 
        Messages.MessageDate, 
        Messages.ValueDate, 
        Messages.MessageReference, 
        Messages.Beneficiary, 
        Messages.StatusId,
        MessageStatus.Status, 
        BICProfile.BIC
FROM    Messages 
        INNER JOIN MessageStatus 
            ON Messages.StatusId = MessageStatus.Id 
        INNER JOIN MessageTypes 
            ON Messages.MessageTypeId = MessageTypes.MessageTypeId 
        INNER JOIN BICProfile  
            ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId 
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  Messages.MessageTypeID, 
                    MessageDate = MAX(Messages.MessageDate)
            FROM    Messages
                    INNER JOIN BICProfile  
                        ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId 
            WHERE   BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue'
            AND     Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
            GROUP BY Messages.MessageTypeID
        ) AS MaxMessage
            ON MaxMessage.MessageTypeID = Messages.MessageTypeID
            AND MaxMessage.MessageDate = Messages.MessageDate
WHERE   BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue'
AND     Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6);
```

*N.B This second method will return multiple rows per message type if the latest message date is common among more than one message. This behaviour can be replicated in the first query by replacing `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK`*

---

**EDIT**

If you will have multiple messages with the same date and only want to return one of them you need to expand the ordering within the row_number function, i.e. if you wanted to pick the message with the maximum id when there were ties you could make it:

```
RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Messages.MessageTypeId 
                                ORDER BY Messages.MessageDate DESC,
                                        Messages.MessageID DESC)
```

So the full query would be:

```
WITH AllMessages AS
(   SELECT  MessageTypes.MessageType, 
            Messages.MessageDate, 
            Messages.ValueDate, 
            Messages.MessageReference, 
            Messages.Beneficiary, 
            Messages.StatusId,
            MessageStatus.Status, 
            BICProfile.BIC,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Messages.MessageTypeId 
                                            ORDER BY Messages.MessageDate DESC,
                                                    Messages.MessageID DESC)
    FROM    Messages 
            INNER JOIN MessageStatus 
                ON Messages.StatusId = MessageStatus.Id 
            INNER JOIN MessageTypes 
                ON Messages.MessageTypeId = MessageTypes.MessageTypeId 
            INNER JOIN BICProfile  
                ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId 
    WHERE   BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue'
    AND     Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
)
SELECT  MessageType, 
        MessageDate, 
        ValueDate, 
        MessageReference, 
        Beneficiary, 
        StatusId,
        Status, 
        BIC 
FROM    AllMessages
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: For performance reasons it seems like a single subquery would be better than using the with clause (don't know how big the table is), or inline views. If he for some reason does not want ties, he could add a second subquery to choose, in the event of a tie, what next condition determines which row to pick.

Comment: What makes you think the two table/index scans required with the subquery will be faster than the one required when using `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: Because the with clause temporarily creates a table with the result set and cannot be indexed.

Comment: @ShWiVeL That is not even a little bit true. The with clause (or common table expression) is more like an inline view, the definition is expanded to the main query and any predicates can be pushed up or down the execution plan. Any indexes on the underlying tables are still used if relevant.

Comment: It can be either or (at least in Oracle), depending on what the optimizer chooses, unless you force it one way or the other with a hint. But I don't see why you would take that route over a subquery on message date. The general reasons for using the with clause aren't really here, because it's a simple problem to begin with.

Comment: In SQL Server the CTE is **never** materialised, in fact there is a [connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/) requesting that there be a query hint that allows the materialisation you claim happens by default. The reason for using the Common Table expression is simply tidiness (somewhat subjective) it is no different placing the entire CTE as a subquery in the from clause instead. As explained before, the benefit of using ROW_NUMBER over the subquery is that it means only a single scan of the messages table, instead of the two required with a subquery.

Comment: Gareth, there could well be same date for the same message type. However, i think your code above will handle it. the message date has a time stamp on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT MT.MessageType
    ,X.MessageDate
    ,X.ValueDate
    ,X.MessageReference
    ,X.Beneficiary
    ,X.StatusId
    ,X.STATUS
    ,X.BIC
FROM MessageTypes MT
OUTER APPLY -- or CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT TOP 1
    M.MessageDate
    ,M.ValueDate
    ,M.MessageReference
    ,M.Beneficiary
    ,M.StatusId
    ,MS.STATUS
    ,B.BIC
FROM Messages M
INNER JOIN MessageStatus MS
    ON M.StatusId = MS.Id
INNER JOIN BICProfile B
    ON M.SenderId = B.BicId
WHERE (B.BIC = 'someValue')
    AND M.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
    AND M.MessageTypeId = MT.MessageTypeId
ORDER BY M.MessageDate DESC
) X
```

Comment: Missing `TOP 1` (or `TOP 1 WITH TIES` depending on requirements) from the APPLY, but other than that +1 for doing the additional method that I left out.

Comment: @GarethD slip of the keys. I was looking after so many things when writing it. Thanks, it has been corrected

Comment: Ok, if I have several messages of the same type with the exact same time, then it doesn't return the most recent. If I included the MessageId, both yours and @GarethD's example return Test61, the last message Id was Test73

Comment: @CSharpNewBee If they have the "exact same time" then how do you define the most recent? They are by definition equally recent. If you want to return all these messages simply change the `TOP 1` above to `TOP 1 WITH TIES`. If you only want the one with the highest Message ID, add `MessageID` to the order by clause inside the APPLY - `ORDER BY M.MessageDate DESC, m.MessageID DESC` (The same applies to the ordering inside the `ROW_NUMBER` function in my answer).

Comment: Thanks @GarethD, just got to work through these now.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, if i could of spilt the points I would of. thanks for chipping in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple subquery to get the laste messagedate for each message type and use that to filter in on the last message. See below:

**If you want the last message for each category, only where the status of that message is 4, 5, or 6: (no result for that category if the status of the message is something else)**

```
SELECT MessageTypes.MessageType MessageType,
       Messages.MessageDate,
       Messages.ValueDate,
       Messages.MessageReference,
       Messages.Beneficiary,
       Messages.StatusId,
       MessageStatus.STATUS,
       BICProfile.BIC
  FROM Messages
 INNER JOIN MessageStatus
    ON Messages.StatusId = MessageStatus.Id
 INNER JOIN MessageTypes
    ON Messages.MessageTypeId = MessageTypes.MessageTypeId
 INNER JOIN BICProfile
    ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId
 WHERE BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue'
   AND Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
   and messages.messagedate =
       (select max(x.messagedate)
          from messages x
         where x.messagetypeid = messages.messagetypeid)
```

**If you want the last message for each category, only where the status of that message is 4, 5, or 6: (no result for that category if the status of the message is something else) AND IN THE EVENT OF A TIE YOU WANT THE MESSAGE WITH THE HIGHEST MESSAGE ID**

```
SELECT MessageTypes.MessageType MessageType,
       Messages.MessageDate,
       Messages.ValueDate,
       Messages.MessageReference,
       Messages.Beneficiary,
       Messages.StatusId,
       MessageStatus.STATUS,
       BICProfile.BIC
  FROM Messages
 INNER JOIN MessageStatus
    ON Messages.StatusId = MessageStatus.Id
 INNER JOIN MessageTypes
    ON Messages.MessageTypeId = MessageTypes.MessageTypeId
 INNER JOIN BICProfile
    ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId
 WHERE BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue'
   AND Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
   and messages.messagedate =
       (select max(x.messagedate)
          from messages x
         where x.messagetypeid = messages.messagetypeid)
   and messages.messageid =
       (select max(x.messageid)
          from messages x
         where x.messagetypeid = messages.messagetypeid
           and x.messagedate = messages.messagedate)
```

^^ CHANGE "messageid" to whatever field on table MESSAGES indicates the ID.

**If you want the last message for each category and for each status of 4, 5, and 6 (if any/all exist within that category)**

```
SELECT MessageTypes.MessageType MessageType,
       Messages.MessageDate,
       Messages.ValueDate,
       Messages.MessageReference,
       Messages.Beneficiary,
       Messages.StatusId,
       MessageStatus.STATUS,
       BICProfile.BIC
  FROM Messages
 INNER JOIN MessageStatus
    ON Messages.StatusId = MessageStatus.Id
 INNER JOIN MessageTypes
    ON Messages.MessageTypeId = MessageTypes.MessageTypeId
 INNER JOIN BICProfile
    ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId
 WHERE BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue'
   AND Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
   and messages.messagedate =
       (select max(x.messagedate)
          from messages x
         where x.messagetypeid = messages.messagetypeid
           and x.statusid = messages.statusid)
```

**If you want the last message for each category where the status is 4, 5, or 6: (messages of other statuses not considered)**

```
SELECT MessageTypes.MessageType MessageType,
       Messages.MessageDate,
       Messages.ValueDate,
       Messages.MessageReference,
       Messages.Beneficiary,
       Messages.StatusId,
       MessageStatus.STATUS,
       BICProfile.BIC
  FROM Messages
 INNER JOIN MessageStatus
    ON Messages.StatusId = MessageStatus.Id
 INNER JOIN MessageTypes
    ON Messages.MessageTypeId = MessageTypes.MessageTypeId
 INNER JOIN BICProfile
    ON Messages.SenderId = dbo.BICProfile.BicId
 WHERE BICProfile.BIC = 'someValue'
   AND Messages.StatusId IN (4, 5, 6)
   and messages.messagedate =
       (select max(x.messagedate)
          from messages x
         where x.messagetypeid = messages.messagetypeid
           and x.statusid in (4, 5, 6))
```

Comment: If the latest message for a message type has a status that is not 4, 5, or 6 then this will return no rows for that message type. You need to apply the same predicates to your subquery as you do to the outer query to ensure the correct results are returned.

Comment: However, if OP's intent is to filter in on the last message for each category only where the status is 4/5/6, then it should return no rows for such categories. In that case the last line should be left out.